# Why does telnet work and netcat fail with this Twisted example?

Tags: python, twisted, telnet, netcat

I'm following a [Twisted tutorial](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/core/howto/tutorial/intro.html)and tried the following code from that article:

```
# Read username, output from non-empty factory, drop connections

from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols import basic

class FingerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, user):
        self.transport.write(self.factory.getUser(user)+"\r\n")
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class FingerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = FingerProtocol

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.users = kwargs

    def getUser(self, user):
        return self.users.get(user, "No such user")

reactor.listenTCP(1079, FingerFactory(moshez='Happy and well'))
reactor.run()
```

I tried `nc localhost 1079` and it just hangs: no replies.  But then `telnet localhost 1079` works just fine.  Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using wireshark, I figured out the following: `telnet` was sending 0x0d and then 0x0a (ie, "\r\n") for the line terminator.  However `netcat` was sending only 0x0a.  This was on Ubuntu (and also on OS X).

Apparently the `LineReceiver` protocol in Twisted requires the \r in order to raise the "line received" event.

There are at least 6 versions of `netcat` out there, but the one on OS X (which is close to FreeBSD) has a `-c` option that appends \r\n to the end of each line.  Using this option fixes the problem.

```
$ nc -c localhost 1079 
moshez
Happy and well
```

Note: `LineReceiver` has a class variable called `delimiter` that allows any EOL character to be used.  Setting `delimiter = '\n'` obviates the need for the `-c` option to netcat.

Comment: This is 100% the correct answer, so you should accept your own answer :)

Comment: The site requires that I wait 2 days before I can do so. :)

Answer (score 2):

On linux, you need to use CRLF as EOL

From the nc man page:

> -C, --crlf (Use CRLF as EOL) .
>              This option tells Ncat to convert LF.  line endings to CRLF. when taking input from standard input..  This is useful for talking to some stringent servers directly from a terminal in one of the many common plain-text protocols that use CRLF for end-of-line.